# Invalid column name error when column exists

Tags: sql

I keep trying to run this query but it keeps telling me the column name does not exist when it clearly does: [first_name proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO6iL.png) this is driving me mad what am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT customers.customer_id, orders.order_id, orders.date_ordered, orders.order_total, orders.collection_method, orders.staff_id
FROM customers INNER JOIN orders on customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
WHERE first_name = James
```

Answer (score 3):

You should escape string values with single quotes:

```
WHERE first_name = 'James'
```

Otherwise, they are treated as identifiers.

Comment: wow it was that simple haha! Thanks a lot, i feel a bit stupid now though